# WTForms: Passing extra arguments while writting custom validation

Tags: python, wtforms

While writing [custom validation for wtforms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/validators.html), is it possible to pass extra argument( like request)

For e.g

```
class MyForm(Form):
  name = TextField('Name', [Required()])

  def validate_name(form, field):
    if len(field.data) > 50:
        raise ValidationError('Name must be less than 50 characters')
```

I need to pass request object( or non form object), if possible to validate_name method. Is there any way for doing it?

Comment: What web framework are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easier way to proceed would be to pass the `request` object to your form and store it as an attribute.

You could do this through the `__init__` method , or by doing `my_form.request = request`.

Then, you `validate_name` method can access the `request` at  `self.request`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make a custom validator for wtforms like Length(min=1, max=45) and other validators and able to pass arguments I went to look for a source code of the wtforms validators and found that it's class:

[image]
https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/_modules/wtforms/validators/#DataRequired

so I created a class with **init** function that will takes the arguments i pass to the validator and must provide **call** function to able to call this class as done in Length validator and others (**call**) -> will let you able to call the class as a function and within that call you can add your custom validation

example of full code

```
class myValidator():

    def __init__(self, length=0):
        self.length = length

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if len(field.data) > self.length:
            # here add new error to the wtforms field
            field.errors += (ValidationError("{} max length is {}".format(field.name, self.length)),)

class SignupForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                                validators=[Length(min=1, max=45), myValidator(length=2)])
```

and here is the final result

[image]

###### note that length is given to the **init** function and I set the length to the class then I will be able to use this property within the **call** method, and also the **call** method will recive the 3 arugments (self the class itself, form the form sent by wtforms to the validator and field the field that applied validation for it)

in my opinion looking for core/source of existing thing will give idea how to implement it

for more info about **init** and **call**:
https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/11/__init__-in-python-an-overview.html
https://geekpython.in/init-and-call-method