# WTForms: passing another container to validator

Tags: python, wtforms

Having already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241330/wtforms-passing-extra-arguments-while-writting-custom-validation) answer, I'm having trouble getting my custom WTForm validator to accept another arg.

How my code is structures is that I have a form_create() method that is called via the following:

```
    form = other_file.form_create(
        form='page_settings',
        data=data,
        all_applications=all_applications,
    )
```

all_applications being a dict I need to index through for one of my validators. form_create looks like the following:

```
def get_form(form=None, *args, **kwargs):
    class Form(wtf.Form):
        if form == 'page_settings':
            my_host_name = HostName('Hostname', validators=[wtf.validators.DataRequired(), validate_hostname, validate_config])
```

I want validate_config to use data from the field and from all_applications, but even after putting it in HostName's **init** method as such:

```
class HostName(wtf.StringField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('validators', [
            wtf.validators.DataRequired(),
        ])
        all_applications = kwargs.setdefault('all_applications')
        super(HostNameField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I keep getting errors like ‘Form’ object has no attribute ‘all_applications’

The custom validator in question looks like this:

```
def validate_config(form, field, all_applications):
    if (some logic here is true):
        raise wtf.ValidationError(
            'some error string here'
        )
```

Any ideas as to how I can get a custom validator to accept another container like `all_applications`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `all_applications` as an attribute of the field when the form is being initialised, then access it via the field in the validator.

```
def validate_config(form, field):
    if field.data and field.all_applications is not None:
        if field.data not in field.all_applications:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid config')


class F(Form):

    foo = StringField(validators=[validate_config])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        all_applications = kwargs.pop('all_applications', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Make all_applications an attribute of field foo
        self.foo.all_applications = all_applications


>>> from webob.multidict import MultiDict

>>> f = F(formdata=MultiDict(foo='a'), all_applications={'a': 1})
>>> f.validate()
True

>>> f = F(formdata=MultiDict(foo='b'), all_applications={'a': 1})
>>> f.validate()
False
>>> f.errors
{'foo': ['Invalid config']}
```